# Insert a variable into another variable Javascript

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this:

ORIGINAL

```
var key_word = {'dentists'};

var pageOptions = { 
  'query': 'cars',
  'hl': 'en'
};
```

I want to insert the variable 'key_word' into where it says cars:

NEW CODE - entire code

```
<div id="adcontainer1"></div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
var key_word = "dentists";

var pageOptions = { 
  'pubId': 'pub-999999999999999',
  'query': function(){ return key_word; },
  'hl': 'en'
};

var adblock1 = { 
  'container': 'adcontainer1',
  'number': '1',
  'width': '700px',
  'lines': '1',
  'colorBackground': 'FBFFDB'
};

new google.ads.search.Ads(pageOptions, adblock1);
</script>
```

From the resulting ad, it appears dentists is not being passed correctly.  Instead the ad is running the text 'key word' instead of the variable key_word, which is the text 'dentists'.  Do I have a syntax problem here?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are **very** different.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with 'set dynamically'? Client side (via javascript) or in PHP? Also, the pageOptions variable, is that generated via PHP?

Comment: `var key_word = {'dentists'};` That's not valid javascript. I don't see what this has to do with php.

Comment: The variable originates through php.  Sorry, I put some bad tags on the question, but they are removed.  @Falmarri, you're right...i made that code valid.

Comment: `var pageOptions = { 'query': key_word };`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var key_word = "dentists"
var pageOptions = { 
    'query': function(){ return key_word; },
    'hl': 'en'
};
```

I think you want something like this.

```
adblock1.key_word = pageOptions.query();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I was looking for, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly.  Can you please take a look at the updated code I put in the main question box?

Comment: I can only guess how you are trying to access the query function.  I updated the code.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I'm not sure if I should contatentate the entire thing togther in a text string, then just make var pageOptions = key_word.  The fx return is still brining back the text key_word, not the text dentists.

Comment: You will have to paste more code.  I don't see where you are trying to get key_word.

Comment: Ok, I pasted in 100% of the exact code, except the publishers id.  Forget about the dynamic keyword.  Let's just assume it's statically set to 'dentists' in the var key_word = "dentists" line.  As it current is written, the word dentists is not being passed through.  Thanks by the way....

Comment: I would suggest pageOptions.query = key_word

Comment: Ok, I'll try that - where do I put it in the code?  Also, do I then delete the line in var pageOptions?  Sorry, I don't work with java as much as php and I"m a little lost.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working with:  pageOptions.query = key_word  Thanks a million!!!!!